# Date not being formatted when copied from one datepicker field to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, angularjs-bootstrap

I've recently migrated from Angular 1.2.5 to the most recent version, 1.3-rc.3, and from ui-bootstrap 0.7.0 to ui-bootstrap 0.11.2, and some functionality in my code breaks.

I have two datepickers on one page, which both initially have no value.
When an user inputs a value for the first datepicker (via the datepicker or manually) I want the second datepicker to be populated with thesame date.

Before I migrated this went fine, but now the second date is not being formatted.

The code i'm using...

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <input 
            class="form-control" 
            type="text" 
            name="datumVanaf" 
            ng-model="filter.datumVanaf" 
            placeholder="Datum vanaf (dd-mm-jjjj)" 
            datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" 
            required 
            datepicker-options="{{calendarOpties}}" is-open="kalender.datumVanafOpened"
            clear-text="wis" 
            current-text="Vandaag" 
            close-text="Sluiten" 
            lower-than="{{filter.datumTM}}"
            ng-class="{'error': filterForm.$submitted && filterForm.datumVanaf.$error.required || filterForm.datumVanaf.$error.lowerThan}" 
        />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatumVanaf($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input 
            class="form-control" 
            type="text" 
            name="datumTM" 
            ng-model="filter.datumTM" 
            placeholder="Datum t/m (dd-mm-jjjj)" 
            datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" 
            required 
            datepicker-options="{{calendarOpties}}" 
            is-open="kalender.datumTMOpened"
            clear-text="wis" 
            current-text="Vandaag" 
            close-text="Sluiten"
            ng-class="{'error': filterForm.$submitted && filterForm.datumTM.$error.required || filterForm.datumVanaf.$error.lowerThan}" 
        />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatumTM($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

And a watcher

```
$scope.$watch('filter.datumVanaf', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    logger.info('newValue', newValue);
    if (newValue != undefined && $scope.filter != undefined && $scope.filter.datumTM == undefined && isValidDate(newValue)) {
        $scope.filter.datumTM = newValue;
    }
});
```

The date is begin show in the first input field like this:

**28-09-2014**

But when it is copied in the second field it is not being formatted:

**Sun Sep 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (West-Europa (zomertijd))**

I have no idea why this doesn't work anymore, and I'm having trouble finding similar cases on stackoverflow. I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Editted your question to make it clearer, hope you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

try use a $filter inside your `filter.datumVanaf`'s anonymous function before setting it into the view. So the code could be something similar to this:

```
    $scope.filter.datumTM = $filter('date')(newValue,'dd-MM-yyyy');
```

Haven't tested it, but you get the idea ;)

Ref:

1. [AngularJS Documentation - date usage in javascript](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Thanks Asyene, It took a while before I could test this, because other things got priority. But now I've tried it and it works like a charm.

Comment: Aaarghh, Now it seems that the value of the field $scope.filter.datumTM is actually no longer a date, but a string. This causes the functionality to break when I send it to the backend. I want it to reuse the formatting it does when selecting a date from the datepicker.